# Continuous random variables probability problem

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

In $40$ calculations a student has made $7$ mistakes. If the teacher checks a randomly chosen set of ﬁve of these forty
calculations, what is the probability the the teacher ﬁnds exactly two mistakes?

Not sure where to begin with this problem but I have attempted it.
I Found the probability of finding a wrong question to be $\frac{7}{40}$, 
then I applied a binomial distribtion $(5C2)$($\frac{7}{40}$)$^2$(1-$\frac{7}{40}$)$^3$$=0.1719$

however the correct answer is $0.174$

Comment: "I Found the probability of finding a wrong question to be $\frac{40}{7}$" - Probability must be $\in \langle 0,1 \rangle$ !

Comment: Hi Mondli.K; the binomial distribution is for without replacement, this is a replacement problem so use the hypergeometric distribution and you will get .1741 too.

Comment: Obvious typo there, edited to 7/40. the result of 0.1719 still stands

Comment: You already know it is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The total number of different sets is $\binom{40}{5}=658008$

The number of different sets with $2$ mistakes is $\binom{40-7}{5-2}\cdot\binom{7}{2}=114576$

Hence the probability to choose a set with $2$ mistakes is $\frac{114576}{658008}\approx0.174$

Answer (score 0):

Using the hypergeometric distribution which is for these type I get:

$$mistakes = 7$$

$$ trials = 5 $$

$$ picks = 2 \\$$

$$\frac{\binom{\text{mistakes}}{\text{picks}}
\binom{40-\text{mistakes}}{\text{trials}-\text{picks}}}{\binom{40}{\text{trials}}}\approx.174125$$